# I want to give Internet to the Raspberry Pi via PuTTy

Tags: ethernet, internet, ethernet-port, putty

I can't connect the Raspberry Pi to the internet due to VLAN vulnerabilities. I can connect the Raspberry Pi via Ethernet just in the network to connect to PuTTy. I want to connect the Raspberry Pi via PuTTy to the internet.

Comment: i do not think that PuTTy can be configured as a gateway

Comment: @jsotola I'm not even sure the poster asks about a gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTy is a ssh client running on MS Window$ to connect to a ssh server. I haven't seen a setup usable to route to the internet with it. You have to connect the RasPi to a router or configure MS Window$ (if you use it) to "share internet connections". But this isn't an issue belonging to Raspberry Pi. B.t.w. I don't believe that you use Virtual LANs (VLAN). That must be supported by a managed switch. I think you mean WLAN (Wireless LAN).